# How can I find and fire a function of React using javascript?

Tags: reactjs

My website is built using React , however, to implement personalization using Optimize I have to use javascript.

Issue is I have to show a popup on "Next" button, popup opens but the Next button executes a React function and next page appears. I have to stop the React function being called by the button and show my pop-up only.

How can I find the React function being called on Next button and stop it from getting executed.

I tried stoppropagation method of javascript but no help.

Also, how can I use Chrome console to invoke React function being called on Next button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a junior trying to help you,so my answer won't be so accurate and technical like others,my theory is that you can separate the code and put some more if's in your function so that you don't need to stop the react function ex:

> Inside your component :

```
const codeForNextButton=(popUpNextButton=false)=>{
const [isPopUpOpened,setIsPopUpOpened]=useState(popUpNextButton)
const popup=()=>{ the popup code,here at the end you can set it to be false the isPopUpOpened}
if(!isPopUpOpened){
 <Redirect to="/TheUrlYouWantRedirectTo"/>
//don't forget to import Redirect at the beginning of the code with:
//import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
 }
}
```

Then in the html code or in the html section of the component :

```
<button onClick={()=>codeForNextButton(isPopUpOpened?true:false)}>Next</button>
```

Then in the popup code you set an interval to be opened and closed or something like that

And about your last question,I personally don't know the answer,but I searched and found a stackoverflow answer that is :

> "With React Developer Tools, you can select your component in the tree on the ⚛️Components dev tools tab. Once selected, that component instance can be accessed in the console as $r, allowing you to invoke your function with $r.someFn()"

I hope this was useful for you

Comment: To add personalization on top of any website we can just write javascript code and replace the content or add any functionality. We can't make any changes in the website code itself. So for that reason I can't make any changes on React side.  The only thing I can do is by writing javascript code for handling clicks or show any content.